# What is this new icon in some of the skills?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I notice in this last beta there's a new icon on some of the skills. It looks like a white triangle with a red 'X' on it. Any idea what this icon is suppose to mean?

[image]

Comment: No tears, like the shampoos.

Comment: @Emerica. I needed to leave [this](http://www.theonion.com/articles/johnson-johnson-introduces-nothing-but-tears-shamp,2506/) here...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The icon is saying that Smoke Screen can not be used underwater. It is actually a water drop with an X over it.

Comment: SO unrealistic. Haven't they ever heard of hydrothermal vents? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_vent

Comment: That was a (bad) joke, btw. Also, I'm still figuring out how to do inline links...

Comment: @Alex You use []'s around the text immediately followed by ()'s with the link. For Example: `[here](http://example.org)`