# What does the clock icon mean in Skill Descriptions?

Tags: guild-wars-2

[image: Screenshot of a skill]

I know from ["What is this new icon in some of the skills?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77696/what-is-this-new-icon-in-some-of-the-skills) that the water droplet icon means that a skill can't be used underwater, and the cooldown icon is easy enough to figure out, but **what does this clock icon mean**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was recently added in the [October 7th](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/info/news/Update-Notes-October-7th-2012) patch, though oddly enough they don't actually *list* it there. That symbol represents the activation time and/or channeling time (if it's a skill that channels) in seconds for a skill. Anything that provides [Quickness](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Quickness) will reduce this value (by half).

Comment: It is stupid tho, Renewed Focus has a duration of 3 seconds and the channeling time is 2... how can that be?

Comment: @Lyrion: the skill only activates after two seconds, I think. Think of it as casting time.

Comment: @pleinolijf No it is an instant cast, i have a guardian. The elite skill would be useless if it takes 2 seconds to activate since the damage would already be done.

Comment: for channeling powers, do they do double damage per tick if you have quickness? otherwise quickness would actually be harmful for those powers!